# Why wpf controls have only one command? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

The question is why wpf controls have only one command?

I have this question because I'm creating custom control. I have two events. To make a binding to viewmodel `ICommand` property I need to use `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`. As I think I can create several commands and one who will use my control will have a choice use event for code behind or use these commands for mvvm. In that case no one will have a need to use `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`.

But as I know all standard controls have only one command. And I can't understand and find answer why controls have only one command? Why it is a good pattern and why it is bad to have more than one command in control?

Comment: What would you expect a button to do that you can bind two commands to? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to have multiple commands if your custom control is providing multiple meaningful actions. It's just the typical WPF controls are more focused on one thing. I wouldn't implement a command for every event just to avoid triggers.

Comment: @nvoigt, for example I need to do some continuous action while button is in down state and use for this `MouseDown` event or `MouseUp` event. And I am writing app in mvvm style. In that case I can't use code behind and best way is to use event triggers. But if class would have commands like `MouseDownCommand` and `MouseUpCommand` it will be much more better to use them

Comment: @grek40, why wouldn't you implement a command for every event if it can sometime save time and decrease XAML size for developer who will use your control?

Comment: *In that case I can't use code behind* Nope. MVVM != no codebehind. Codebehind is for your UI logic. Create a custom control, hang an ICommand or more on it, and use your codebehind to implement the desired UI effects.

Comment: I even create code behind for resource dictionaries if I feel like handling some events to improve the visual appearence or user input. Having anything named `MouseDownCommand` in a viewmodel would be an MVVM anti-pattern since the viewmodel would start assuming specifics about the user interface. MVVM doesn't ban code behind, it bans business logic from the view layer.

Comment: @YuryKerbitskov, for scenario "do some continuous action while button is in down state" there is [RepeatButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is why wpf controls have only one command?

There is no rule that a control must be limited to a single command.  It's true that buttons, by way of `ICommandSource`, expose only a single command.  It makes sense for most controls, which are relatively simple and have a single responsibility.  However, complex controls can certainly define more than one.

`Slider`, for instance, declares and handles several commands:

```
public static RoutedCommand IncreaseLarge { get; }
public static RoutedCommand DecreaseLarge { get; }
public static RoutedCommand IncreaseSmall { get; }
public static RoutedCommand DecreaseSmall { get; }
public static RoutedCommand MinimizeValue { get; }
public static RoutedCommand MaximizeValue { get; }
```

Granted, `Slider` does not expose these commands via instance-level properties, as there is little reason to allow them to be overridden.  They are all handled by the slider itself, and they all do the same thing: they change the current value of the slider.  The user only expects something to happen when the value changes; *how* it changes it not terribly relevant.  The important information can generally be communicated via a single `ValueChanged` event.

I cannot, off the top of my head, think of a stock WPF control that *does* allow more than one command to be assigned to each instance.  That said, I can easily *conceive* of such a control.  Consider, for example, a 'spinner' control with up and down buttons.  While the up/down buttons on a spinner *could* be used to manipulate a single scalar value like the slider, you might decide to use it in an entirely different way.  For example, you might want the up/down buttons to function like elevator call buttons.  If the spinner exposes a separate `UpCommand` and `DownCommand`, you retain the flexibility necessary to accommodate both scenarios.

If you have a custom control, and you feel it is appropriate to define more than one command, then go right ahead.

#### Continuous Command Invocation with `RepeatButton`

You mentioned this use case in one of your comments:

> I need to do some continuous action while button is in down state

WPF ships with a `RepeatButton` control for precisely this purpose.  You've already seen it used for the arrow buttons in the default `ScrollBar` template.  Just bind the `Command` to whatever action you want to repeat while the button is held in its pressed state:

```
<RepeatButton Content="Hold to Repeat Command"
              Command="{Binding YourRepetitiveCommand}" />
```

Comment: well, with continuous action it was just an example, but I didn't know about RepeatButton. In real I'm writing live search control and commands are `BeginFilter` and `StopFilter`. Well, now I understand that it will be good to create two commands. And another approach is to create one command on filter state. I think both of variants are appropriate to my task.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a `ToggleFilter` command.  If it hasn't begun yet, it begins.  If it has, it stops.  Don't try to map events to commands--there isn't necessarily a one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Because you only *need* one command. Sure, it could have been an array, but that's more markup/hassle for 0 benefit 99.99% of the time.

In that 0.01% case, you can just have a command that... fires off several other commands (or even just several methods) writing a `CompositeCommand` class is simple enough that it is left to the programmer, much like `DelegateCommand`.

In your case, you are saying you have two unique events that will be command bindable; that seems perfectly fine. Its just that buttons only have one interesting event (click) that is common enough for command support.

Comment: Do you want to say that most of the button events are using very seldom and that's why there is only one command? Does this is the main criteria which I should take in mind when thinking about create command for event or not?

Comment: @YuryKerbitskov Yes, I'm saying that not nearly enough people care about a button event besides click, and also that most of the other events don't make sense with a VM handler, so adding a command for them doesn't make sense. I would think likelihood of usage is a good criteria for you, yes.

Comment: More precisely, one cares that the button was 'invoked'.  It does not matter _how_ it was invoked.  It may have been clicked, an access key may have been pressed, or the user might have used voice input.  What matters is that the user intended some action to be performed, and the `Command` property lets you specify that action.